MUI CSS Variables Still Cause SSR Flickering
I have a NextJS application (App Router) (14.1.4) using MUI (6.0.0-alpha.13) and have the following in RootLayout
<body>
<AppRouterCacheProvider>
    <CssVarsProvider defaultMode={"system"}>
        <CssBaseline/>
        <InitColorSchemeScript defaultMode={"system"}/>
        {children}
    </CssVarsProvider>
</AppRouterCacheProvider>
</body>

If I set my OS preferred theme to dark and refresh the page, I still get light mode for just under a second.  Inspecting element shows that in that first second, the HTML element looks like so
<html lang="en" data-color-scheme="dark">

Before then changing to the following after hydration
<html lang="en" data-color-scheme="dark" data-mui-color-scheme="dark">

In addition, I also get a hydration mismatch warning of the following
Warning: Extra attributes from the server: data-color-scheme
    at html
    at RootLayout (webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./src/app/layout.tsx:21:11)
...

Where line 21 of layout.tsx is the <InitColorSchemeScript defaultMode={"system"}/> line.
It seems that <InitColorSchemeScript defaultMode={"system"}/> is not correctly adding an attribute with mui contained and is instead producing data-color-scheme="dark" which has no effect.
I have followed the MUI documentation for CSS variable usage for version 6.0.0-alpha.12 here.
My fix in the meantime is to copy the MUI provided InitColorSchemeScript.js file, modify
export const DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE = 'data-color-scheme';
to
export const DEFAULT_ATTRIBUTE = 'data-mui-color-scheme';
and add suppressHydrationWarning={true} to the html tag
